# Debian : unable to RUN apt-get -y install postgresql (error 100)

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to build a Docker image with the following Dockerfile :

```
FROM apache/nifi
USER root

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install postgresql

WORKDIR /opt/nifi/nifi-current/
COPY postgresql-42.4.2.jar /opt/nifi/nifi-current/lib/postgresql-42.4.2.jar
COPY ojdbc8.jar /opt/nifi/nifi-current/lib/ojdbc8.jar
```

Nifi image is Debian 11 bullseye.

When I try to build with this Dockerfile I have the following error :

```
> [12/15] RUN apt-get -y install postgresql:
#0 0.547 Reading package lists...
#0 0.948 Building dependency tree...
#0 1.069 Reading state information...
#0 1.217 The following additional packages will be installed:
#0 1.217   cron exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light gsasl-common guile-2.2-libs
#0 1.217   libbsd0 libc-l10n libedit2 libevent-2.1-7 libfribidi0 libgc1 libgdbm-compat4
#0 1.217   libgdbm6 libgnutls-dane0 libgnutls30 libgsasl7 libidn11 libllvm11 libltdl7
#0 1.217   libmailutils7 libmariadb3 libmd0 libmpdec3 libntlm0 libperl5.32 libpopt0
#0 1.217   libpq5 libpython3.9 libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib
#0 1.218   libsensors-config libsensors5 libunbound8 libz3-4 locales logrotate
#0 1.218   mailutils mailutils-common mariadb-common media-types mysql-common perl
#0 1.218   perl-modules-5.32 postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13
#0 1.219   postgresql-client-common postgresql-common ssl-cert sysstat
#0 1.220 Suggested packages:
#0 1.220   anacron checksecurity exim4-doc-html | exim4-doc-info eximon4 file
#0 1.220   spf-tools-perl swaks gdbm-l10n dns-root-data gnutls-bin lm-sensors
#0 1.220   mailutils-mh mailutils-doc perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
#0 1.220   | libterm-readline-perl-perl make libtap-harness-archive-perl postgresql-doc
#0 1.220   postgresql-doc-13 libjson-perl isag
#0 1.499 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#0 1.499   cron exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light gsasl-common guile-2.2-libs
#0 1.499   libbsd0 libc-l10n libedit2 libevent-2.1-7 libfribidi0 libgc1 libgdbm-compat4
#0 1.499   libgdbm6 libgnutls-dane0 libgsasl7 libidn11 libllvm11 libltdl7 libmailutils7
#0 1.500   libmariadb3 libmd0 libmpdec3 libntlm0 libperl5.32 libpopt0 libpq5
#0 1.500   libpython3.9 libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib libsensors-config
#0 1.500   libsensors5 libunbound8 libz3-4 locales logrotate mailutils mailutils-common
#0 1.500   mariadb-common media-types mysql-common perl perl-modules-5.32 postgresql
#0 1.500   postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13 postgresql-client-common
#0 1.500   postgresql-common ssl-cert sysstat
#0 1.502 The following packages will be upgraded:
#0 1.503   libgnutls30
#0 22.59 1 upgraded, 50 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
#0 22.59 Need to get 73.1 MB of archives.
#0 22.59 After this operation, 316 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#0 22.59 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 cron amd64 3.0pl1-137
#0 22.59   Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 22.59 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 perl-modules-5.32 all 5.32.1-4+deb11u2
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgdbm6 amd64 1.19-2
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgdbm-compat4 amd64 1.19-2
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libperl5.32 amd64 5.32.1-4+deb11u2
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 perl amd64 5.32.1-4+deb11u2
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgnutls30 amd64 3.7.1-5+deb11u1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpopt0 amd64 1.18-2
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 logrotate amd64 3.18.0-2+deb11u1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libc-l10n all 2.31-13+deb11u3
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 locales all 2.31-13+deb11u3
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 media-types all 4.0.0
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 exim4-config all 4.94.2-7
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 exim4-base amd64 4.94.2-7
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libevent-2.1-7 amd64 2.1.12-stable-1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libunbound8 amd64 1.13.1-1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgnutls-dane0 amd64 3.7.1-5+deb11u1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libidn11 amd64 1.33-3
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 exim4-daemon-light amd64 4.94.2-7
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgc1 amd64 1:8.0.4-3
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libltdl7 amd64 2.4.6-15
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 guile-2.2-libs amd64 2.2.7+1-6
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmd0 amd64 1.0.3-3
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:24 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libbsd0 amd64 0.11.3-1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libedit2 amd64 3.1-20191231-2+b1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:26 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libfribidi0 amd64 1.0.8-2+deb11u1
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.59 Err:27 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libntlm0 amd64 1.6-3
#0 22.59   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:28 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libz3-4 amd64 4.8.10-1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:29 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libllvm11 amd64 1:11.0.1-2
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:30 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mailutils-common all 1:3.10-3
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:31 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.7
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:32 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mariadb-common all 1:10.5.15-0+deb11u1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:33 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmariadb3 amd64 1:10.5.15-0+deb11u1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:34 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpython3.9-minimal amd64 3.9.2-1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:35 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmpdec3 amd64 2.5.1-1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:36 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpython3.9-stdlib amd64 3.9.2-1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:37 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpython3.9 amd64 3.9.2-1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:38 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmailutils7 amd64 1:3.10-3+b1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Ign:39 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 13.7-0+deb11u1
#0 22.60 Err:40 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsensors-config all 1:3.6.0-7
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:41 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsensors5 amd64 1:3.6.0-7
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:42 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mailutils amd64 1:3.10-3+b1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:43 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 postgresql-client-common all 225
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Ign:44 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 postgresql-client-13 amd64 13.7-0+deb11u1
#0 22.60 Err:45 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 ssl-cert all 1.1.0+nmu1
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:46 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 postgresql-common all 225
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Ign:47 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 postgresql-13 amd64 13.7-0+deb11u1
#0 22.60 Err:48 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 postgresql all 13+225
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 22.60 Err:49 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 sysstat amd64 12.5.2-2
#0 22.60   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.35 Err:50 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 gsasl-common all 1.10.0-4+deb11u1
#0 23.35   Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 23.35 Err:51 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 libgsasl7 amd64 1.10.0-4+deb11u1
#0 23.35   Unable to connect to security.debian.org:http:
#0 23.35 Err:39 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 13.7-0+deb11u1
#0 23.35   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.35 Err:44 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 postgresql-client-13 amd64 13.7-0+deb11u1
#0 23.35   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.35 Err:47 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 postgresql-13 amd64 13.7-0+deb11u1
#0 23.35   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/cron/cron_3.0pl1-137_amd64.deb  Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/perl/perl-modules-5.32_5.32.1-4%2bdeb11u2_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gdbm/libgdbm6_1.19-2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gdbm/libgdbm-compat4_1.19-2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/perl/libperl5.32_5.32.1-4%2bdeb11u2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/perl/perl_5.32.1-4%2bdeb11u2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls30_3.7.1-5%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/popt/libpopt0_1.18-2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/logrotate/logrotate_3.18.0-2%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-l10n_2.31-13%2bdeb11u3_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.31-13%2bdeb11u3_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/media-types/media-types_4.0.0_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4-config_4.94.2-7_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4-base_4.94.2-7_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libe/libevent/libevent-2.1-7_2.1.12-stable-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/unbound/libunbound8_1.13.1-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls-dane0_3.7.1-5%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11_1.33-3_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4-daemon-light_4.94.2-7_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/gsasl/gsasl-common_1.10.0-4%2bdeb11u1_all.deb  Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (IP_ADRESS). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libgc/libgc1_8.0.4-3_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libt/libtool/libltdl7_2.4.6-15_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/guile-2.2/guile-2.2-libs_2.2.7%2b1-6_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libm/libmd/libmd0_1.0.3-3_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libb/libbsd/libbsd0_0.11.3-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libe/libedit/libedit2_3.1-20191231-2%2bb1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fribidi/libfribidi0_1.0.8-2%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libntlm/libntlm0_1.6-3_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/gsasl/libgsasl7_1.10.0-4%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to security.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/z/z3/libz3-4_4.8.10-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-11/libllvm11_11.0.1-2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mailutils/mailutils-common_3.10-3_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mysql-defaults/mysql-common_5.8%2b1.0.7_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.36 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.5/mariadb-common_10.5.15-0%2bdeb11u1_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.5/libmariadb3_10.5.15-0%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.9/libpython3.9-minimal_3.9.2-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mpdecimal/libmpdec3_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.9/libpython3.9-stdlib_3.9.2-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.9/libpython3.9_3.9.2-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mailutils/libmailutils7_3.10-3%2bb1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/postgresql-13/libpq5_13.7-0%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors-config_3.6.0-7_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors5_3.6.0-7_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mailutils/mailutils_3.10-3%2bb1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-client-common_225_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/postgresql-13/postgresql-client-13_13.7-0%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/ssl-cert/ssl-cert_1.1.0%2bnmu1_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-common_225_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/postgresql-13/postgresql-13_13.7-0%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql_13%2b225_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sysstat/sysstat_12.5.2-2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 23.37 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
Dockerfile:54
--------------------
  53 |     RUN apt-get -y update
  54 | >>> RUN apt-get -y install postgresql

--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install postgresql" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Comment: Your Docker base image seems to have incorrect URLs in its `apt` source lists. Have a look at them and correct them. Since `dockerbase_nifi:v01` does not seem to be a publicly available image, I'm unable to inspect it.

Comment: @Kusalananda I updated my question, the image is from apache/nifi. How to look at them and correct the apt source lists, and know what to add/modify ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your updated Dockerfile in the question, but it's evident from the error that you are not showing the whole Dockerfile (the error occurs on line 54), and I have no way of knowing what other modifications you make to the base image before running that `apt-get` command.

Comment: The other lines are commented, that's why. These lines above are the ones I am using. Maybe there errors come because I am behind a proxy. I don't know if I have to update the sources list.

Comment: I ran `docker build .` with your Dockerfile (minus the two `COPY` lines) in the current directory, and that completed with no errors. That's all I can say.

Comment: How can I debug ?